# Counting intermittent time series events in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

The task is about counting events in an intermittent time series which has `df` as below:

```
           Temperature top_lim  bottom_lim
Timestamp               
2015-10-30  26.479969   40     25
2015-10-31  25.500000   40     25
2015-11-01  25.500000   40     25
2015-11-02  27.916858   40     25
```

The code

```
df.plot( y='Temperature', figsize=(16, 10),) 

plt.axhline(y=40, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=25, color='b', linestyle='-')

df['top_lim'] = 40
df['bottom_lim'] = 25

plt.fill_between(df.index, df['bottom_lim'], df['Temperature'],
                where=(df['Temperature'] >= df['bottom_lim'])&(df['Temperature'] <= df['top_lim']),
                facecolor='orange', alpha=0.3)

mask = (df['Temperature'] <= df['top_lim'])&(df['Temperature'] >= df['bottom_lim'])
plt.scatter(df.index[mask], df['Temperature'][mask], marker='.', color='black')

cumulated_time = df.index[mask].diff().sum()
plt.title(f'Cumulative time in range = {cumulated_time}')
plt.show()
```

produced a graph like this
[image]

How can I edit the code to calculate, **for each spike**:

the total number of seconds for which `Temperature`>40, which preferably gives a table looks something like this:

```
           Temperature top_lim  bottom_lim 49duration
Timestamp               
2015-10-30  26.479969   40     25           5
2015-10-31  25.500000   40     25           3
2015-11-01  25.500000   40     25           0
2015-11-02  27.916858   40     25           4
```

where `49duration` represents the number of seconds that `Temperature` >49 at a spike?

Comment: for each day how many times have you been above a certain temperature? being the day (time stamp) the index?

Comment: your expected output data doesn't really match with your sample data. You should really come up with some simple example and expected output **from that example**.

Comment: so `df['Temperature'].gt(49).groupby(level=0).transform('sum')`?

Comment: @ansev The number of times is random in a day. Could you please briefly explain `df['Temperature'].gt(49).groupby(level=0).transform('sum')`? Thank you

Comment: @QuangHoangThanks for your advice. I'll try to do it next time.